# Rich text not displaying on record lightning page

Tags: richtextarea, lightning-record-page

I created a rich text section on a record lightning page, where I put a link pointing to an excel sheet. The link is well displayed in edit screen, but not in creation screen when I press the button "New" of the record I want to create.

The edit and create screen both point to the same page layout. Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).What exactly do you mean by well displayed? If you've got examples of the behaviour you're talking about it would be useful to add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar situation. Looks like lightning record page cuts all non-field related components in record create mode (record view/edit mode shows them all). Unfortunately, I haven't found any decent documentation regarding this matter. I just simply tested it.